# Select between two times in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, for-loop, if-statement

I used the `output = result.set_index('times').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('H')).mean()` and then the `output.between_time('11:00', '12:00')` to get only the two hours that I want. What I'm having a hard time figuring out is if there is a way to select the 12:00:00 but if there isn't, the 11:00:00 is the one used instead if possible. Here's what the output snippet looks like:

```
times                   A           B           C           D
1996-12-04 11:00:00     NaN     0.081826    0.112259    0.134100    
1996-12-04 12:00:00     NaN     0.080180    0.107108    0.126118    
....
2017-01-15 11:00:00     0.246591    0.309864    0.332677    0.362805    
2017-01-15 12:00:00     0.242433    0.301287    0.325492    0.355687    
2017-01-16 11:00:00     0.131201    0.155804    0.170489    0.180293    
2017-01-16 12:00:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     
2017-01-17 11:00:00     0.078308    0.093946    0.104750    0.110965    
2017-01-17 12:00:00     0.083883    0.097341    0.108580    0.114755    
2017-01-18 11:00:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     
2017-01-18 12:00:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     
2017-01-19 11:00:00     0.092868    0.109789    0.120100    0.125462    
2017-01-19 12:00:00     0.098974    0.113243    0.125806    0.130909
```

And the solution I'm looking for:

```
times                   A           B           C           D
1996-12-04 12:00:00     NaN     0.080180    0.107108    0.126118    
2017-01-15 12:00:00     0.242433    0.301287    0.325492    0.355687    
2017-01-16 11:00:00     0.131201    0.155804    0.170489    0.180293    
2017-01-17 12:00:00     0.083883    0.097341    0.108580    0.114755    
2017-01-19 12:00:00     0.098974    0.113243    0.125806    0.130909
```

I'm assuming I need to use a for loop with an if statement, but I'm just starting to learn Python so I haven't gotten the hang of it yet.

Comment: Nice, you could make your example a bit smaller (many irrelevant columns now)

Comment: I've simplified it. My data just contains 22 columns, with a lot of NANs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if necessary remove all NaNs rows by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html) and aggregate [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html).

Methods [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) are necessary, because after groupby dates lost times.

```
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=0)
df = df.reset_index().groupby(df.index.date).last().set_index('times')
print (df)
                            A         B         C         D
times                                                      
1996-12-04 12:00:00       NaN  0.080180  0.107108  0.126118
2017-01-15 12:00:00  0.242433  0.301287  0.325492  0.355687
2017-01-16 11:00:00  0.131201  0.155804  0.170489  0.180293
2017-01-17 12:00:00  0.083883  0.097341  0.108580  0.114755
2017-01-19 12:00:00  0.098974  0.113243  0.125806  0.130909
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks. I thought it was more complicated than it would be. I'm used to IDL and recently took up Python. Now I just need to figure out to select just the 2002-2013 data.

Comment: how would I go about doing the `.between_time('23:00','00:00')`. I used the `.first()` which works for the most part, but the issue is that `2012-12-27 23:00:00 2012-12-28 00:00:00` is that it handles the 27th as its own date since there is no `2012-12-27 00:00:00` when it should only take the `2012-12-28 00:00:00`

Comment: hmmm, it seems hard question. The best is create new question, I hope you get some good answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is to have the first of each group. Imagine you would add a column `day` and a column `hour`, then you could sort the values, group them by date, and take the last one of each group (12 if available otherwise 11).

```
result = df.sort_values('hour').groupby('day').apply(lambda g: g[-1]).reset_index()
```

You can fill these columns before or calculate them on the fly, e.g.

```
df.groupby(df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.date))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select according to a value that is in your dataframe, you can use

```
    df.reset_index().set_index('times').loc['12:00:00']
```

**Main drawback** : The given value has to be in the index.

#### Output:

```
            index       A           B           C           D
times                   
12:00:00    2017-01-15  0.242433    0.301287    0.325492    0.355687
12:00:00    2017-01-16  NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
12:00:00    2017-01-17  0.083883    0.097341    0.108580    0.114755
12:00:00    2017-01-18  NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
12:00:00    2017-01-19  0.098974    0.113243    0.125806    0.130909
```

If you want to give a time interval you can do the same :

```
df.reset_index().set_index('times').loc['12:00:00':'13:00:00']
```